# Problems with dynamically generating id reference in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, this

I have a page with a list of audio play files; the viewer clicks the link and this plays the corresponding audio file.

When a new link is clicked, all current audio needs to cease. Including that link, if it's already playing. So; each link is a start/stop for that audio file.

I have constructed a JQuery / JS script that should do this, but the scripts seems to have problems with the `this` declaration and with being dynamic.

The Audio Id is the same as the Text within the anchor link.

HTML:

```
<audio id="Perihelion" src="/music/Perihelion.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
<audio id="MassedVerses" src='/music/MassedVerses.mp3' preload="auto"></audio> 

<a class='music'>Perihelion</a>
<br><BR>
<a class='music'>Massed Verses</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   /* PlayOn variable is required to know if the click on the link is
       starting or stopping THAT audio */
    var playOn = true;

   var sounds = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
    $(".music").click(function (event) { 
        /* Prevent anchor default */
        event.preventDefault();

        /* Stopping all audio, on link click no matter what */
        for( i=0; i < sounds.length; i++) {
            sounds[i].pause();
        }


        /* Trying to dynamically generate id reference */ 
        var audioName = $(this).innerHTML;
        /* remove whitespace from the string */
        audioName = audioName.replace(/\s+/g, "");
        var fullAudioIdName = "#" + audioName;
        var audio = $(fullAudioIdName)[0];

        if (playOn === true) {
            audio.play();
            playOn = false;
            $(this).html("Stop "+audioName);
        }  else {
            audio.pause();
            $(this).html(audioName);
            playOn = true;
        }

    });
});
```

## My Process reasoning

- User clicks one of the anchors - the anchor is called "Perihelion";
- `this` music class then triggers the JS click function.
- The `innerHTML` needs to be collected from ***this*** element, and then used as a reference to find the assocaited `<audio>` `id` (removing name white space)
- Re clicking the same link should stop the current audio playing and all audio playing and switch the trigger variable.

## My Problems

> TypeError: audioName is undefined audioPlay.js:10:9

I have tried to use `.toString()` on the innerHTML as well but this also has no success

> $(...).innerHTML is undefined

## My Aim

I want to have a dynamic JQuery / Javascript script so that it can play an audio file whose `<audio>` `id` is the name within the anchor tags.

so:

```
        var audioName = $(this).innerHTML; 
        /* Massed Verses */
        audioName = audioName.replace(/\s+/g, "");
        /* MassedVerses */ 
        var fullAudioIdName = "#" + audioName;
        /* #MassedVerses */
        var audio = $(fullAudioIdName)[0];
        /* audio is $(#MassedVerses)[0];
```

## What have I missed?

**I hate Javascript. Grumble Grumble...**

Comment: `innerHTML` is an Element property, not a jQuery property.  Use `this.innerHTML` or `$(this).html()` instead.

Comment: @Taplar so ... `$(this).innerHTML` becomes `$(this).html()`

Comment: Yes that seems to work. Thank you.

Comment: Yes.  jQuery does not directly expose Element properties.  To access them you have to use the `prop()` method, or specific utility methods, such as `html()` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the innerHTML property (not method) does not exist for a jQuery object. You must call it on a DOM object (JS)
It's `$("...").html()` or `$("...").get(0).innerHTML` as the get method returns a pure JS DOM object.